# SSH doesn't use public key for authentication (Windows)

Tags: git, ssh

I have a VPS (Windows Server 2016) and ran a SSH server on it with OpenSSH for windows. I would run a git server on this VPS so i searched for some tutorials in google and found [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH).
The tutorial for configuring the server side settings is okay and i created a bare git repository. I would connect to the git server with my own computer using SSH public key, but it wants password from me! I tried to save my public generated key from my own PC (without passphrase) in /.ssh/authorized_keys file in server but it didn't worked. When i use this `git clone user@IP_ADDRESS:<repo dir>` command to clone the existing repository from the server it keeps telling me that i should enter a password:

```
Cloning into 'central'...
user@IP_ADDRESS's password:
```

I tried to skip the password prompt by just pressing the enter also tried root for password but it didn't help anyway.
Although i used `ssh -Tv git@IP_ADDRESS` to see step by step what is happening then i realized that the `publickey` authentication getting skipped and process goes for `password` auth method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was about the privileges of current user group on the server. In my case that user has administrator privileges so the SSH would search in the `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh/administrator_authorized_keys` for the public keys. For normal user accounts in Windows, SSH automatically would go for `/users/{username}/.ssh/authorized_keys` file where i was copying my machine public SSH key. So i moved my public key to the `administrator_authorized_keys` file and everything works fine now.
Thanks to [@EdKenbers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13763860/edkenbers) for replying.

Comment: It's _administrator**s**_authorized_keys_ (missing s). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#administrative-user

Answer (score 1):

git@IP_ADDRESS's means that you are connecting with "git" user not "root", does it exists in the server? The ~/.ssh/authorized_keys have to be added to the user's home.

```
/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or in your case (Edited I was thinking in Linux :) ):

```
C:\Users\git\.ssh\authorized_keys
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I can add explanation about Private-Public Keys authentication if you need it. Just ask for it.

Comment: Actually i'm using the user which is available on the server not "git" (I edited the post). So it should use the authorized_keys file to give me access, but it doesn't. Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: In the documentation I see : Create Windows users for all Git users.
Which users have you created?

Comment: You have to use one of this users in the ssh connection:
ssh {user}@IPADDRESS

Comment: Why do you say that you can't copy the public key to authorized_keys? The public key is a plain text file, you can open it with an editor and copy the content.

Comment: Basically, first make ssh with user+password  work and then try to make it work with public key, it's the correct way to configure it.

Comment: I could save the public key in the authorized_keys file, my problem was about SSH and skipping the publickey authentication method. Thank you for help anyway, i will test your solution if it works it will become the answer (: